# Lost access to drawer icon for center button on CyanogenMod 7

Tags: cyanogenmod, launcher, home-screen-shortcuts, htc-thunderbolt, app-drawer

I am running CyanogenMod 7 on my HTC Thunderbolt and somehow I inadvertently removed the function for the center button on my home screen between the phone and web browser icons.  This middle button used to bring me to the drawer where every installed application is listed, not just the ones on my home screen.

How can I restore the middle button functionality to get access to applications in my drawer?

Comment: Is the button still visible and non-functional, or is it missing from the action bar?

Comment: Missing from action bar, shows as Star icon and click gives message: `No application defined yet, drop something here!`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you just dragged the tray shortcut off the action bar accidentally. Try doing the following:

- Long press on an empty space on any home screen
- Select "Launcher Actions" from the menu that appears
- Select "Open/Close App Drawer"
- Drag the new shortcut back onto middle button of the Action Bar